# Can't import "ImportObject" from python "wasmer"

Tags: python, webassembly

So easy to reproduce that I'm surprised that nobody has reported it yet.

```
pip install wasmer
python -c 'from wasmer import ImportObject'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'ImportObject' from 'wasmer' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/wasmer.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
```

"ImportObject" class is described in [readme](https://github.com/wasmerio/python-ext-wasm#the-importobject-class) and presented in [examples](https://github.com/wasmerio/python-ext-wasm/blob/master/examples/imported_function.py#L1). I've checked that proper 0.4.1 version of "wasmer" was installed. Also I checked the newest tagged [version](https://github.com/wasmerio/python-ext-wasm/releases/tag/0.4.2-beta.11) of "wasmer" which fails with the same error. Do I do something totally wrong?

UPD: generate_import_object() function doesn't work also:

```
python -c "from wasmer import Module; Module.generate_import_object()"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: type object 'Module' has no attribute 'generate_import_object'
```

And this code gives the same result:

```
wasm_bytes = open('binary.wasm', 'rb').read()
module = Module(wasm_bytes)
import_object = module.generate_import_object()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The library in pip is outdated. The current version is from March, 2nd, and the necessary changes were implemented only on June, 2nd. 0.4.2 beta version is outdated also (May, 19). So, the only way now is manual build. Probably the library will be updated in a couple of weeks.

See more details in this thread: https://github.com/wasmerio/python-ext-wasm/issues/215.